# Private and public subnets in the same az in application load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I need to expose public and private APIs all of them with /api/... path. For this purpose I've created one public and one private subnet in each availability zone. Then the application load balancer only allows me to add one of these subnets per availability zone.

How can I have public and private apis bellow the same initial path in aws?

Comment: Public/private subnets are a networking function, and have no relation to public/private API endpoints under your API.

Comment: @Matt I think that the obvious way to make an API endpoint private is to place the service behind that endpoint in a private subnetwork, so It has a relation from my point of view

Comment: But that's not how it works.

Comment: Ok, and returning to the original question: How can I have public and private apis bellow the same initial path in aws?

Comment: You should remove the talk of subnets from your question and more clearly explain private and public apis.

Comment: what are public and private APIs in your point of view exactly?

Comment: In my point of view a public api can be consumed by anyone over the internet and a private api can only be consumed inside the VPC.